# Title of subplots should change while looping according to values in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector in Matlab `X=[1 4; 5 6; -1 -2]`and the following loop over graphs where the title of subplots should change while looping

```
for h=1:size(X,1)
subplot(1,3,h)
plot(1:0.1:10, log(1:0.1:10)) %it is just for the purpose of the question
hold off
title('X=X(h,1), Z=X(h,2)') 
end
```

At `h=1` the title should be `X=1, Z=4`, at `h=2` the title should be `X=5, Z=6`, etc...

How can I do that?

Comment: search string concatenation in matlab and `num2str` may help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does what you want:

```
title(['X=' num2str(X(h,1)) ', Z=' num2str(X(h,2))])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is pretty much purpose built for this type of string formatting:

```
title(sprintf('X=%d, Y=%d', X(h,:)))
```

Which gives the desired outputs:

```
'X=1, Y=4'
'X=5, Y=6'
'X=-1, Y=-2'
```